# Contact form - cannot get email to send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, email

I am trying to create a basic form to send an email and here is how it looks:
http://www.unitedserbians.com/contact_us.html

I have everything working and buttoned up, except I cannot get the actual email to be sent once the form has completed processing. My function executes as my field validations work great and I can see the correct values are being grabbed from the form by un-commenting the JAVA script code "alert (dataString);return false;" and even the .ajax executes because I get "Contact Form Sent! We will be in touch soon." message displayed but the actual email never gets sent. I am guessing that something is missing in the process.php file. I cannot trace to see where the issue occurs or if my process.php ever executes. Should the file live in the same directory with JAVA script? or at main directory bin folder? Or is there something I am blindly missing in the process code? Can someone spot what am I missing please? Much appreciated in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<div class="content_resize">
  <div class="mainbar">
    <div class="article">
      <h2><span>Send us E-Mail</span></h2>
      <div id="contact_form">
      <form action="" form name="contact">
      <fieldset>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <label for="name" id="name_label">Your Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
            <label2 class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="email" id="email_label">Your Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
            <label2 class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="website id="phone_label">Your Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
            <label2 class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="submit" name="imageField" id="submit_btn" src="images/submit.gif" class="send" />
          </li>
        </ol>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JAVA script:**

```
  $(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $(".send").click(function() {
    // validate and process form here

    $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
        $("label2#name_error").show();
        $("input#name").focus();
        return false;
    }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
        $("label2#email_error").show();
        $("input#email").focus();
        return false;
    }
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        if (phone == "") {
        $("label2#phone_error").show();
        $("input#phone").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var message = $("textarea#message").val();

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;
    // alert (dataString);
    // return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "bin/process.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#contact_form').html("<div id='send_message'></div>");
        $('#send_message').html("<h2>Contact Form Sent!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>");
      }
    });
    return false;

  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php

    $email_to = "XXXXX@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Message sent using contact form.";


    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required

    $message = $_POST['message'];


    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Phone Number: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

Comment: Too much code. Why are you supressing error output for the mail function if there is no mail sent?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean? Can you please be a little more specific.

Comment: Look at your own code. Where did you get it from if you don't know what it does? Why is there a `@` sign before the `mail` function? Google that.

Comment: Php and sendmail are never a good combo (just never seemed to work for me). What I do a lot is create a php socket into my local mail server and send mail with SMTP.

Comment: Even if I remove @ it doesnt work. I was simply testing because I saw on a forum that someone was using so it was worth trying it out because I am desperate. Remove the @ before mail function still doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry I should state that @ surpresses the error but removing it doesnt throw an error when I click submit, which is why I am asking where does the process.php file suppose to live? Maybe its not even executing at all.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your host doesn't like the $email_from address.  I think most hosts are restrictive about sending using a From address that isn't associated with that host (this is so to not enable spammers).  Try using no-reply@yourdomain.com or something like that, or even better an address that really exists, as your From address.  The Reply-To can still be the address the user enters (after you check that it is valid).

Comment: Def good thing to keep in mind. I have done testing with existing email address and it still doesnt work.